# How can I keep the Java client high availability when using TDengine?

Tags: java, database

I build a 3-node TDengine database cluster with 192.168.31.1/2/3. I'm using JDBC connector.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:TAOS://192.168.31.1:6030/db
```

If the node 192.16.31.1 is down, the other node will continue to service. However, the client won't work again. Is there any way for it to switch to the proper node?

Answer (score 0):

set the value is null

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:TAOS://:/db
```

and the driver will check the taos.cfg file.
config taos.cfg like this:

```
firstEp 192.168.31.1
secondeEp 192.168.31.2
```